# how to display inner object of array of objects in javascript? in the code below how to display prev_evolution and next_evolution?

Tags: javascript

```
var pokemon = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: "display" ... in what way? how are you "displaying" other properties for example

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to get next_evolution and prev_evolution of all object.

```
var result = pokemon.map(a => {
                      var x={}; 
                      x.next_evolution=a.next_evolution; 
                      x.prev_evolution=a.prev_evolution;
                      return x;});
console.log(result);
```

```js
var pokemon = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }
]

    var result = pokemon.map(a => {
                  var x={}; 
                  x.next_evolution=a.next_evolution; 
                  x.prev_evolution=a.prev_evolution;
                  return x;});
    console.log(result);
```